# How is the connection between validate.js and i18n files is made to set the value of parameters "{ }"?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, validation

If we write a custom validate method using validate.js, something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customValidate", function (value, element, params)
```

We can then use this "params" as a parameter in my i18n properties file.

So now in my properties file, I can have:

```
foo.bar.sparta = This is a 300 {0}
```

Now when we use this property, it dynamically gets the value passed in the param of the validator, How is it possible?

Comment: Are you saying this is happening now? Or are you asking how to make this happen?

Comment: I know that this happens, I am asking how does it happens? How does the parameters from the param of a validator method get passed to a i18n file?